# How to print register values in GDB?

Tags: gdb, cpu-registers

How do I print the value of `%eax` and `%ebp`?

```
(gdb) p $eax
$1 = void
```

Comment: Use `layout reg` to have gdb show a table of all integer and flag registers, highlighting the one(s) changed by the previous instruction.  See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for example.

Answer (score 311, accepted):

`info registers` shows all the registers; `info registers eax` shows just the register `eax`. The command can be abbreviated as `i r`

Comment: I get: Invalid register `%eax'
And if I just do "info registers" eax does not show up.  Yet I am looking at my code assembly in the IDE where a EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal has been generated with the instruction: test %eax, %eax
This is in XCode running gdb.   Why is gdb not reporting the eax register?

Comment: Same problem: %eax is in the code, yet print $eax shows void.

Comment: Bridgette's answer works for me. geekosaur's answer is mostly right, but you need to omit the % sign, so the command for a specific register is `info registers eax`. I'm not sure if this is different for different versions of gdb, though.

Comment: I was searching for the same thing for lldb, so let me just note that: for lldb, the command is `register read [eax]`

Comment: If you want to display the register values continuously as you step through the code you can use `display`. For e.g. `display $eax`.

Answer (score 68):

If you're trying to print a specific register in GDB, you have to omit the % sign. For example,

```
info registers eip
```

If your executable is 64 bit, the registers start with r. Starting them with e is not valid.

```
info registers rip
```

Those can be abbreviated to:

```
i r rip
```

Answer (score 49):

There is also:

```
info all-registers
```

Then you can get the register name you are interested in -- very useful for finding platform-specific registers (like NEON Q... on ARM).

Comment: This taught be about registers I didn't know exist :-)

Comment: On my machine, this prints `eax`, `ecx`, and other standard registers hidden by `info registers`. This should probably be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 19):

- If only want check it once, `info registers` show registers.
- If only want watch one register, for example, `display $esp` continue display esp registers in gdb command line.
- If want watch all registers, `layout regs` continue show registers, with TUI mode.

Answer (score 19):

**Gdb commands**:

- `i r <register_name>`: print a single register, e.g `i r rax`, `i r eax`
- `i r <register_name_1> <register_name_2> ...`: print multiple registers, e.g `i r rdi rsi`,
- `i r`: print all register except floating point & vector register (xmm, ymm, zmm).
- `i r a`: print all register, include floating point & vector register (xmm, ymm, zmm).
- `i r f`: print all FPU floating registers (`st0-7` and a few other `f*`)

Other register groups besides `a` (`all`) and `f` (`float`) can be found with:

```
maint print reggroups
```

as documented at: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Registers.html

**Tips**:

- `xmm0` ~ `xmm15`, are 128 bits, almost every modern machine has it, they are released in 1999.
- `ymm0` ~ `ymm15`, are 256 bits, new machine usually have it, they are released in 2011.
- `zmm0` ~ `zmm31`, are 512 bits, normal pc probably don't have it (*as the year 2016*), they are released in 2013, and mainly used in servers so far.
- Only one serial of xmm / ymm / zmm will be shown, because they are the same registers in different mode. On my machine ymm is shown.

Comment: The link is broken, it is now: https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Registers.html#Registers

Answer (score 13):

**`p $eax` works as of GDB 7.7.1**

Tested as of GDB 7.7.1, the command you've tried  works:

```
set $eax = 0
p $eax
# $1 = 0
set $eax = 1
p $eax
# $2 = 1
```

This syntax can also be used to select between different union members e.g. for ARM floating point registers that can be either floating point or integers:

```
p $s0.f
p $s0.u
```

From [the docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html):

> Any name preceded by ‘$’ can be used for a convenience variable, unless it is one of the predefined machine-specific register names.

[and](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Registers.html):

> You can refer to machine register contents, in expressions, as variables with names starting with ‘$’. The names of registers are different for each machine; use info registers to see the names used on your machine.

But I haven't had much luck with control registers so far: OSDev 2012 http://f.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=25968 || 2005 feature request https://www.sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2005-03/msg00158.html || alt.lang.asm 2013 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.lang.asm/JC7YS3Wu31I

**ARM floating point registers**

See: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8992/floating-point-registers-on-arm/20623#20623

Comment: It's great to be able to use registers in expressions with this `$` syntax.

Comment: Oh wow, I hadn't realized this feature was at all recent.  How did you do stuff like `set $eax = 4` before that?

Comment: @PeterCordes that was just "tested at version" BTW, not first implemented at, clarified it. I likely hand't ever done that before 2015, I'm too young for it :-)

Answer (score -1):

Easiest for me is:

```
(gdb) x/x $eax
```

First `x` stands for e**x**amine and second `x` is hex. You can see other formats using:

```
(gdb) help x
```

You can easily print strings with `x/s $eax` or return addresses with `x/a $ebp+4`.

Comment: `x $eax` does not show `eax`'s contents. It shows the contents at address the `eax` has as its contents.

Comment: you will get an error when the address can't be accessed— yes it still shows the contents from "error". So I think it is not adequate to use `x` to access register. The commands have their own purposes.