# combination of objdump and gdb

Tags: c, gdb, reverse-engineering, objdump

It is about reverse engineering in linux: if I have a .c file and I compile it with gdb all it's fine. But how can I obtain the same result starting from an executable file?
I tried `objdump -M intel -D file` to disassemble but then I would like to assemble it again in order to open it with gdb (instead if I directly open the executable with gdb I can't do things like putting breakpoints and viewing registers); I tried with nasm and gcc but they found errors in the syntax.

Comment: Just a note: NASM uses a variant of the Intel syntax. The GNU assembler prefers AT&T syntax. And I think, you mean: compile a .c file with gcc, and assemble a file with gas (or as for short).

Comment: Within GDB you can set breakpoints with `break` and view registers with [`info registers`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429137/how-to-print-register-values-in-gdb). So could you please clarify your question.

Comment: But if I use gdb with the executable (a downloaded crackme, not compiled and linked by myself) I can't set breakpoints and (that's the main point) I can't view the assembly code (it says "No symbol table is loaded").

Answer (score 0):

If the symbol table has been stripped off, you cannot get it back.
Anyway, you can set breakpoints in GDB on a specific code address with:

```
break *address
```

If you have a hex address, you must precede it with `0x` e.g.:

```
break *0x400506
```

And to print the current register values, you can use `info registers` as also answered in [How to print register values in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429137/how-to-print-register-values-in-gdb)

```
info registers
```

NASM and the GNU assembler use different syntax, that why you cannot easily dissamble with the first and assemble with the latter. NASM uses a variant of the Intel syntax. The GNU assembler prefers AT&T syntax.